# Using SimpleMembership With WPF Applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-client

I started my project using ASP.NET SIMPLE MEMBERSHIP. Now I have the necessity to create a WPF application which can add users to SIMPLEM MEMBERSHIP tables.

In the ASP.NET, I've identified that this is the function to create new accounts:

```
 WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

What would you suggest to implement this feature in a desktop application. I was thinking creating a WCF Web Service, but I don't know how difficult could be creating it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WCF but probably the simplest solution is to include the Asp.net Simple Membership Tables as part of an Entity Framework Model and use the model from within your WPF app. Check out this [post](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model) for more details.

That would, of course, require direct access to your SQL Server and either a SQL Server account with access to the tables referenced from the EF model would have to be used or the app users would have to have access to the SQL Server through integrated security (if using mixed mode authentication with your SQL Server).

Comment: But I don't know how MVC create the hash password and that stuff to popularize the row in the another tables

Answer (score 0):

Why bother?

I would simply have yours users go to a link and register for an account online through an asp.net page. Once registered, offer the WPF/windows client as a download. This stuff is already pretty much all built-in.

That link might help:  http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx